# Git shared repo on jail shell with single user, multiple developers

Tags: git, jail-shell

I have been trying to set up a decent shared repository location for a small team of developers to share code privately (so no github and the likes). The internet in Ethiopia is erratic, slow, and some websites are blocked for no reason I can understand (no bitbucket).

I have a jail shell access on my web server. I managed to compile and install git there, and am hosting a bare repo there. This is working great, the only issue I am concerned with is that all developers will access the account using the same username. Even if I don't share the password, and everyone uploads their public key, I think the username is the same.

Does this cause any problems? I can't think of any, but it seems irregular to do things this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily irregular; just look at the SSH repo specs Github gives you (`git@github.com:path/to/repo/...`). It will be irregular if the account you're giving everyone access to is your primary login. Sharing a username isn't a problem in itself, but you'll effectively be giving all the devs the same access you have to your server.

Answer (score 0):

To your surprise, it is a recommended way of working with GitHub or any repo. SSH is based on authorization and is efficient and advisable.

You can also add a "contributor."" user on GitHub so that you can give them whatever permissions to the main repo you wish.